# Can't delete BigQuery dataset + tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with around 200k tables that I'm trying to delete. I've been using the commandline tool to run `bq rm -r -f datasetID`, but it has only deleted about 4% in 24 hours. (I can only guess at the amount by logging into the web UI and seeing what tables are left). Is there a faster way to get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite late, but here is how I did it:

Install `jq` and gnu `parallel` first. Substitute PROJECT_ID with your project's ID.

`bq ls --project_id PROJECT_ID --max_results=100000 --format=prettyjson | jq '.[] | .id' | parallel --bar -P 10 bq --project_id PROJECT_ID rm -r -f -d`

You might need to tune `-P` parameter's value for better deletion rate.

**Warning**: It will end up deleting all the tables and datasets in your project. You can perform a dry run with `echo`, analyze the output and then finally run the above command:

`bq ls --project_id PROJECT_ID --max_results=100000 --format=prettyjson | jq '.[] | .id' | parallel --bar -P 10 echo bq --project_id PROJECT_ID rm -r -f -d`

Deleted 100K tables across 9K datasets in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so would be to iterate through the tables and delete them individually (possibly in parallel). Or an even faster way could be to set an expiration time on the tables that is only a very short time in the future.

This is not a highly optimized path since we don't often get users who want to delete that many tables at once.